# Updating the model of a scrollpane doesn't update the window

Tags: java, swing

Using `javax.swing`, I created a window displaying a list.
This list has two buttons, allowing to delete or add shop items displayed in the list. Shop items are stored in files.
I'd like to make that when such buttons are clicked, the list updates itself by listing all the files in its specified directory (I need for some reasons this method rather than just directly modifying the list with model.remove().)
However, when I do `model = new DefaultListModel()` , the list simply doesn't update itself.
Below is the code of the panel displaying the list of the shop items.

```
public class ShopWindowPanel extends JPanel
{
    private UserInterface window;
    private JList<String> jList;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private ArrayList<ShopItem> arrayList;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane;

    /**
     * Constructor method.
     * @param window The window linked to the shop window panel. It is used for error pop-ups.
     */
    public ShopWindowPanel(UserInterface window) {
        this.window = window;
        initializePanel();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes the panel.
     */
    public void initializePanel()
    {
        initializeButtons();
        initializeScrollPane();

        add(jScrollPane);

        //setting up the layout of the panel
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane)
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(addButton)
                        .addComponent(deleteButton)
        ));

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane)
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(addButton)
                        .addComponent(deleteButton)
        ));

        gl.linkSize(addButton, deleteButton);

        window.pack();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes the buttons.
     */
    public void initializeButtons() {

        addButton = new JButton("Add");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add a new item and its price in pound (item name, price");

                try
                {
                    String[] itemDetails = text.split(", ");
                    ShopItem shopItemToAdd = new ShopItem();
                    shopItemToAdd.setName(itemDetails[0]);
                    shopItemToAdd.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(itemDetails[1]));
                    shopItemToAdd.save(); //create a new file
                    initializeScrollPane(); //supposed to update the scroll pane
                }
                catch(Exception exception)
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window.getContentPane(), "An error has happened!" + exception.getClass() + ": " + exception.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                ListSelectionModel selmodel = jList.getSelectionModel();
                int index = selmodel.getMinSelectionIndex();
                if (index >= 0) {
                    arrayList.get(index).delete(); //delete the file
                    initializeScrollPane(); //supposed to update the scroll pane
                }
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes the list of the items.
     */
    public void initializeScrollPane() {
        //listing all shop items
        model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        File shopItemFileFolder = new File(ShopItem.shopItemsFolder);
        File[] shopItemsFiles = shopItemFileFolder.listFiles();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<ShopItem>();
        for(int i = 0; i<shopItemsFiles.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                ShopItem currentlyProcessedShopItem = new ShopItem();
                currentlyProcessedShopItem.load(shopItemsFiles[i].getName());

                model.addElement(currentlyProcessedShopItem.getName() + ": £" + (float) currentlyProcessedShopItem.getPrice()/100);
                arrayList.add(currentlyProcessedShopItem);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("A problem has happened with an item.");
            }
        }

        jList = new JList<>(model);
        jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you're creating a new instance of the `JList` (and `JScrollPane`) but they are never added to the screen, simply create the new `ListModel` and apply it to the `JList` you created originally

Comment: Like this? 
  try
  {
   jList.setModel(model);
  }
  catch(NullPointerException e)
  {
   jList = new JList<String>(model);
  }
Because it doesn't work…

Comment: Why not just check to see if the `JList` is `null` or not...or have a separate method which populates the model and one which generates the list/scrollpane

Comment: But this doesn't work. The list displayed by the window isn't updated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate method which does thing more than generates the `ListModel`...

```
public ListModel<String> initializeListModel() {
    //listing all shop items
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    File shopItemFileFolder = new File(ShopItem.shopItemsFolder);
    File[] shopItemsFiles = shopItemFileFolder.listFiles();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<ShopItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < shopItemsFiles.length; i++) {
        try {
            ShopItem currentlyProcessedShopItem = new ShopItem();
            currentlyProcessedShopItem.load(shopItemsFiles[i].getName());

            model.addElement(currentlyProcessedShopItem.getName() + ": £" + (float) currentlyProcessedShopItem.getPrice() / 100);
            arrayList.add(currentlyProcessedShopItem);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("A problem has happened with an item.");
        }
    }
    return model;
}

public void initializeScrollPane() {
    jList = new JList<>(model);
    jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
}
```

Then in you button's `ActionListener`s, call this method and apply the result to your `JList`...

```
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add a new item and its price in pound (item name, price");

            try {
                String[] itemDetails = text.split(", ");
                shopItemToAdd.setName(itemDetails[0]);
                shopItemToAdd.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(itemDetails[1]));
                shopItemToAdd.save(); //create a new file
                jList.setModel(initializeListModel());
            } catch (Exception exception) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ShopWindowPanel.this, "An error has happened!" + exception.getClass() + ": " + exception.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            ListSelectionModel selmodel = jList.getSelectionModel();
            int index = selmodel.getMinSelectionIndex();
            if (index >= 0) {
                jList.setModel(initializeListModel());
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Cheers! Actually, your code doesn't seem to work: it adds new items to the scrollbar but doesn't remove the previous ones. I did some tweaks on your code however and now it appears to be working! I'll post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @MMCXCVII Since you didn't provide a runnable example, I had to "guess", but `jList.setModel(initializeListModel());` replaces the existing model for a new model, removing all the previous elements. Since `initializeListModel` creates a new instance of `ListModel`, it's impossible for it to container any "old" elements, unless they are getting pulled from your basic data source to start with, which would be beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to update the scrollbar we must keep track of the model field and not reinitialize it. So, we have to use the same model object and its methods. One solution could be:

```
/**
 * This method initializes the list of the items.
 */
public void initializeModel() {
    try
    {
        model.removeAllElements();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException exception)
    {
        //putting store items in the field model
        model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    }

    try
    {
        ShopWindow.update();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Problem updating the list of shop items!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<ShopWindow.getList().size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            model.addElement(ShopWindow.getItem(i).getName() + ": £" + (float) ShopWindow.getItem(i).getPrice()/100);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("A problem has happened with an item.");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the scroll pane.
 */
public void initializeScrollPane()
{
    initializeModel();
    jList = new JList<String>(model);
    jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `try-catch` blocks as flow control, use a `if-else` statement ... and basically that's what I said...several times

Comment: Are you talking about the handling of the NullPointerException? In this case, how can I test if model is defined or not?

Comment: `if (model == null)` ... `Exceptions` should be used for the "unexpected" use cases that "might" occur, you know that the `model` might be `null`, so simply do a check for it

Comment: But this method is also called to initialize the field `model`, so any reference to `model` like `model == null` will throw a `NullPointerException`, won't it? Unless you advise me to initialize the field `model` in another method.

Comment: Why would `if something == null` through a `NullPointerException`, if `model == null` that's your trigger to create a new model, otherwise, it's already been created

Comment: `model` is a field of the JPanel object, but it's supposed to be initialized in this method. So, if I put at the beginning of the method `if(model == null)`, I got a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, because this method is called when the window is created and is supposed to initalize `model`.

Comment: `if (model == null) {model = new DefaultListModel<String>();}` now it's not null